# Is there a Russian language equivalent of dict.cc?

Tags: resource-request, electronic-resources, vocabulary

I am starting to learn Russian and I am looking for a good dictionary to use. When I learned German, dict.cc was my bible. Along with long lists of every possible meaning for given a given word in German or English, as well as derived phrases, the most useful thing was that there was always given a frequency number for each each meaning of each word. Though dict.cc does technically have a Russian version, it is nowhere near as comprehensive as the German version and is much smaller. And though dictionary.reverso.net has very close to what I am looking for and is very good with Russian, there doesn't seem to be any indication of word frequency. Is there anything for Russian that resembles the German dict.cc or something like Reverso but with word/definition/meaning frequency indications for Russian?

Comment: Guess you can find it here: https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/833/resources-for-learning-russian